# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL

Tags: json, typescript, iot

I am trying to control some devices remotely by getting sensor data: Temperature, Humidity, etc..
I don't know why but in the code there is something that is not working perfectly. I struggle reading and re-reading the code but still .. I could not figure our the origin of the error:

node:internal/errors:464
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined
at Object.openSync (node:fs:577:10)
at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
at readTd (C:\Users\Mehdi\Desktop\WS2022\IoT_Mehdi\iotrlws2122cons2-ge37vok\6_averageSensors.js:175:24)
at C:\Users\Mehdi\Desktop\WS2022\IoT_Mehdi\iotrlws2122cons2-ge37vok\6_averageSensors.js:201:46
at step (C:\Users\Mehdi\Desktop\WS2022\IoT_Mehdi\iotrlws2122cons2-ge37vok\6_averageSensors.js:33:23)
at Object.next (C:\Users\Mehdi\Desktop\WS2022\IoT_Mehdi\iotrlws2122cons2-ge37vok\6_averageSensors.js:14:53)
at fulfilled (C:\Users\Mehdi\Desktop\WS2022\IoT_Mehdi\iotrlws2122cons2-ge37vok\6_averageSensors.js:5:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}

```
import { Logger, createLogMessage } from './utils/Logger';
import { AffordanceType, RecipientType, Operation } from './utils/LogTemplate';
import { HttpsClientFactory } from "@node-wot/binding-http";
import ConsumedThing from "@node-wot/core/dist/consumed-thing";
import { Servient } from "@node-wot/core";
import fs = require("fs");
import path = require("path");
import { exit } from "process";
import { ThingDescription } from "wot-typescript-definitions";


const servient = new Servient();
let creds = { 
    "urn:dev:ops:32473-sensehat-001": {
        // Here the username and password I Provided you with
        "username": "xxxxxx",
        "password": "xxxxxx"

    },
    "urn:dev:ops:32473-sensehat-002": {
        // Here the username and password I Provided you with
        "username": "xxxxxx",
        "password": "xxxxxx"

    },
    "urn:dev:ops:32473-sensehat-003": {
        // Here the username and password I Provided you with
        "username": "xxxxxx",
        "password": "xxxxxx"

    },
    "urn:dev:ops:32473-sensehat-004": {
        // Here the username and password I Provided you with
        "username": "xxxxxx",
        "password": "xxxxxx"

    },
    "urn:dev:ops:32473-HueIndoorSensor-1": {
        // Here the username and password I Provided you with
        "username": "xxxxxx",
        "password": "xxxxxx"

    },
    "urn:dev:ops:32473-HueIndoorSensor-2": {
        // Here the username and password I Provided you with
        "username": "xxxxxx",
        "password": "xxxxxx"

    },
    "urn:dev:ops:32473-HueOutdoorSensor-1": {
        // Here the username and password I Provided you with
        "username": "xxxxxx",
        "password": "xxxxxx"

    },
};

servient.addClientFactory(new HttpsClientFactory(null));
servient.addCredentials(creds);
const delay = async (ms: number) => {
    await new Promise<void>(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));
}

var logger = new Logger();

async function readLoggedProperty(thing: any, propertyName: string, options?: any): Promise<any> {
    var logMsg = createLogMessage(
        { name: propertyName, type: AffordanceType.Property },
        1,
        Operation.Readproperty,
        RecipientType.Thing,
        thing.getThingDescription().title,
        thing.getThingDescription().id,
        null
    );
    logger.addMessage(logMsg);
    // logger.saveMessages("6_averageSensors", "HTTP");

    let ret = await thing.readProperty(propertyName, options);

    var logMsg = createLogMessage(
        { name: propertyName, type: AffordanceType.Property },
        1,
        Operation.Invokeaction,
        RecipientType.Controller,
        thing.getThingDescription().title,
        thing.getThingDescription().id,
        ret
    );
    logger.addMessage(logMsg);
    // logger.saveMessages("6_averageSensors", "HTTP");

    return ret;
}



async function invokeLoggedAction(thing: any, actionName: string, params?: any, options?: any): Promise<any> {
    var logMsg = createLogMessage(
        { name: actionName, type: AffordanceType.Action },
        1,
        Operation.Invokeaction,
        RecipientType.Thing,
        thing.getThingDescription().title,
        thing.getThingDescription().id,
        params
    );
    logger.addMessage(logMsg);
    // logger.saveMessages("6_averageSensors", "HTTP");

    await thing.invokeAction(actionName, params, options).then(function (ret) {
        var logMsg = createLogMessage(
            { name: actionName, type: AffordanceType.Action },
            1,
            Operation.Invokeaction,
            RecipientType.Controller,
            thing.getThingDescription().title,
            thing.getThingDescription().id,
            ret
        );
        logger.addMessage(logMsg);
        logger.saveMessages("6_averageSensors", "HTTP");

        return ret;
    })
}

let td_sensHats1: ThingDescription;


function readTd (tdPath: string){
    let read_file = fs.readFileSync(tdPath);
    var td = JSON.parse(read_file.toString());
    return td;
  }

var ConsumedthingsHat=[]
var ConsumedthingsHue=[]
async function main() {
var array_SenseHat = ["SenseHat1.json","SenseHat2.json","SenseHat3.json","SenseHat4.json"];        //declaration 


var array_Hue=["Hue Indoor Sensor 1.json","Hue Indoor Sensor 2.json","Hue Outdoor Sensor.json"];        //declaration 

        await servient.start().then(async (WoT) => {
        for (let m = 0 ; m < 5; m ++)
        {
            
            var td = readTd(array_SenseHat[m]);
            const thing = await WoT.consume(td) as ConsumedThing;
            console.log(thing)
            ConsumedthingsHat.push(thing);
        }

                for (let m = 0 ; m < 4; m ++)
        {
            
            var td = readTd(array_Hue[m]);
            const thing = await WoT.consume(td) as ConsumedThing;
            console.log(thing)
            ConsumedthingsHue.push(thing);
        }
    

        // await servient.start().then(async (WoT) => {
        const thing1 = await WoT.consume(ConsumedthingsHat[0]);
        // Average Teamperature
        let array_tempvalues: number[] = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            // var td = await readTd(array_SenseHat[j]);
            // const temp_Value = await WoT.consume(td) as ConsumedThing;
            let temp = await readLoggedProperty(ConsumedthingsHat[j], "temperature");
            await array_tempvalues.push(temp);
            
        }

        let avgTemp = array_tempvalues.reduce((total, actual_TempValue, index, array) => {
            return (total + actual_TempValue) / array.length;
        })

        let payload1 = { "avgTmp": avgTemp.toFixed(2) };
        await invokeLoggedAction(thing1, "showMessage", payload1);

        // Avg pressure on hat2
        const thing2 = await WoT.consume(ConsumedthingsHat[1]);
        let arrayPressureValues: number[] = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            // const element = await WoT.consume(ConsumedthingsHat[j]);
            let pressure = await readLoggedProperty(ConsumedthingsHat[j], "pressure");
            arrayPressureValues.push(pressure);
        }

        let avgPress = arrayPressureValues.reduce((total, actual_Pressure, ind, array) => {
            return (total + actual_Pressure) / array.length;
        })

        let payload2 = { "avgPressure": avgPress.toFixed(2) };
        await invokeLoggedAction(thing2, "showMessage", payload2);

        // Avg humidity on hat2
        let arrayHumidity: number[] = [];
        const thing3 = await WoT.consume(ConsumedthingsHat[2]);
        for (let j = 0; j <5; j++) {
            // const element = await WoT.consume(ConsumedthingsHat[j]);
            let humid = await readLoggedProperty(ConsumedthingsHat[j], "humidity");
            arrayHumidity.push(humid);
        }

        let avgHumid = arrayHumidity.reduce((total, actual_Humidity, ind, array) => {
            return (total + actual_Humidity) / array.length;
        })

        let payload3 = { "textString": avgHumid.toFixed(2) };
        await invokeLoggedAction(thing3, "showMessage", payload3);
// Avg humidity on hat2

        let arrayLight: number[] = [];
        const thing4 = await WoT.consume(ConsumedthingsHue[0]);
        for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            // const element = await WoT.consume(ConsumedthingsHue[j]);
            let info = await readLoggedProperty(ConsumedthingsHat[j], "lightInformation");
            arrayLight.push(info["state"]["lightlevel"]);
        }

        let avgLight = arrayLight.reduce((total, actual_Light, ind, array) => {
            return (total + actual_Light) / array.length;
        })
        let payload4 = { "textString": avgLight.toFixed(2) };
        await invokeLoggedAction(thing4, "showMessage", payload4);

        await delay(5000).then(async () => {
            for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                const element1= array_SenseHat[j];
                await invokeLoggedAction(element1,"clear");
                console.log("Nothing Displayed");
            }
        })
    })
}

main()
```

Looking forward for help

Comment: your `array_SenseHat` has 4 elements, yet you are iterating `for (let m = 0 ; m < 5; m ++)` and accessing `array_SenseHat[m]`, ie with the last iteration you are accessing `array_SenseHat[4]` which is of course undefined and passing that to `readTd()` which is passing that to `readFileSync()`. And `readFileSync()` throws an error if the `path` argument is undefined ...

Comment: This answers my question, thanks. I am used to another iteration system, that's why.